# MongoDB installation over AWS cloud

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

MongoDb has latest feature called mongoDB atlas which work as database as a service(DAAS) and handle the cloud configuration, data backup and replication for developer. In case if anybody want to manage the cloud configuration separately, then what could be the best solution to get the better IO rate.

1. Use the high end AWS EC2 instance which has large Ephemeral
   memory.
2. Use the medium EC2 instance like t2.medium and use the
   EBS whenever required?
3. Use the small/medium EC2 instance and use the s3
   for storage purpose?

Also how hard is to maintain the sharding and backup by yourself instead of using Atlas?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar questions two years ago. However, as someone who is currently managing both an Atlas cluster and an on-premise sharded cluster, I would say that your question itself is reason enough to go with Atlas. Atlas should really be your default strategy unless you want to invest significant time in becoming a MongoDB DBA. With Atlas, your risk will be far lower and your costs similar, especially if you count your labour costs. There may be a business case with very large data volumes to go on-premise but it's not something to be taken lightly.

Also, I've always used EBS storage with MongoDB, I don't think you want to use S3. Your instance size very much depends on your application requirements.

Comment: My data is not large enough to go for on-premise solution, but yeah to go with self doing DBA invest more time and reliability may be bit less than Atlas. So preferable to go Atlas so better solution. Also your say about Mongo Cloud Manger, how it is different from Atlas

Comment: I use Cloud Manager as well and it has a very similar interface to Atlas -- the biggest difference is that it doesn't host your database. So you would use Cloud Manager with an existing on-premise cluster for monitoring, management and back-ups. Atlas looks like your best bet. Good luck Ritesh!

Comment: Thanks Mark, i will go forward with Atlas

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB will perform well on medium EC2 instances. As @user1710884 suggested, EBS is your best choice. You'll want at least three instances in a replica set to get started (for availability, maintenance, etc). That's what Atlas gives you at a minimum.

It's possible to manage your own backups by taking system snapshots or doing periodic dumps. But if you want the point-in-time restore features that Atlas affords, you'll probably not want to implement that from scratch.

It's MongoDB's declared goal that Atlas should make it irresponsible to deploy MongoDB in the cloud, meaning that there are no use cases that Atlas cannot support and the added value always exceeds the costs of self-management. I have high confidence they've met that goal for many if not most use cases.

Your best bet is to get an Atlas instance, get familiar with it, build your successful business on it, and then worry about economizing or manually solving the problems that Atlas was designed to solve.

Comment: I think after going trough Atlas, it will be time waste to go manually process of setup. Yeah, going to Atlas is better than doing all alone.